# Perl: Three parts of code works independently of each other, when mixed, the script fails

Tags: perl

I have the following script to make pdf from jpgs,  tifs, and pngs. Each part (starting with #indepedently works OK) works fine. In other words, when I comment the JPG part, the script works for PNG, when I comment JPG and PNG part, it works for TIFs. However, it fails to work for all the extensions: JPG, PNG and TIF. I want the script to look for JPGs in a folder. If they are found, a pdf should be created (and only then, I do not want an empty pdf) and the script should exit. If there are no JPGs, the script should look for PNGs. If they are found, a pdf should be created and the script should exit. If there are no PNGs, the script should look for TIFs. If they are found, a pdf should be created and the script should exit.
The script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use PDF::API2;
use strict;
use warnings;

# assume all just one directory path
my $folder = join(' ', @ARGV);

# deal with dos paths
$folder =~ s|\\|/|g;

$folder =~ s|/$||;

my $pdf_file = $folder . '.pdf';

die "Not a folder!\n" unless -d $folder;
die "There's already a pdf of that name!\n" if -f $pdf_file;

my $pdf = PDF::API2->new;

#indepedently works OK - JPG
foreach my $file ( glob "$folder/*.jpg" ) {
    my $jpg = $file;
    my $image = $pdf->image_jpeg($jpg);
    my $page = $pdf->page();
    $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    my $gfx = $page->gfx;
    $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
}

$pdf->saveas($pdf_file);

#indepedently works OK - PNG
foreach my $file ( glob "$folder/*.png" ) {
    my $png = $file;
    my $image = $pdf->image_png($png);
    my $page = $pdf->page();
    $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    my $gfx = $page->gfx;
    $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
}

$pdf->saveas($pdf_file);

#indepedently works OK - TIF
foreach my $file ( glob "$folder/*.tif" ) {
    my $tif = $file;
    my $image = $pdf->image_tiff($tif);
    my $page = $pdf->page();
    $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
    my $gfx = $page->gfx;
    $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
}

$pdf->saveas($pdf_file);
```

Comment: I don't know what "it fails to work" means, but you probably shouldn't be calling `$pdf->saveas()` after each loop.

Comment: I will correct my post to explain what it fails to work" means. I call `$pdf->saveas()` after each loop because in a folder there would be either JPGs, or PNGs or TIF.

Comment: What do you actually want, though? One PDF file with all types of images, or three PDF files separated by image type?

Comment: I want the script to look for JPGs in a folder. If they are found, a pdf should be created (and only then, I do not want an empty pdf) and the script should exit. If there are no JPGs, the script should look for PNGs. If they are found, a pdf should be created and the script should exit. If there are no PNGs, the script should look for TIFs. If they are found, a pdf should be created and the script should exit. I hope I am more clear now.

Comment: You should definitely [edit] the post and the subject line to reflect that new information, because it changes things quite a bit.

Comment: Write functions.  Then you can write `print "No images to convert\n" if (convert_jpgs($pdf) == 0 && convert_pngs($pdf) == 0 && convert_tifs($pdf) == 0)`.  The functions each return the number of images converted.  You can do your `save` in the functions if you wish, or up in the main code.  You can add parameters to the functions as necessary, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for this, but it sounds to difficult for a perl newbie, and I am one of them. Changing the code above has taken me a lot of time and your suggestions will take me even more.

Comment: @menteith Functions/subroutines are easy to grasp, and you're going to need to learn about them eventually, so it [might as well be now](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)!

Comment: @MattJacob Well, since they are so important I will do my best I will try to implement they in my code.

Comment: Another thing---not sure what your intent was joining `@ARGV` with spaces. Any spaces in the path will break your current incantation of `glob`.

Comment: I created a key in Windows registry to have an option on every folder which allows me to simply right click, choose the right option and have a pdf made. I am not 100% sure but the registry option  was: "C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "D:\test\790024.pl" "%1". I don't have my computer at hand right now so I cannot check it. When it comes to the piece of code you mentioned, I joined `@ARG` with spaces because I tried to avoid not making a pdf when a space character is in the name of a folder. It worked in my first version of the script. Do you see a better option?

Comment: @MattJacob My registry key is as follows:  `"C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\Users\michal\Documents\createpdf\790024.pl" %1`. Do you think replacing `my $folder = join(' ', @ARGV); ` with `my $folder = $#ARGV;` do the trick?

Comment: @menteith No, that will set `$folder` to the index of the last element in the array. You'll need to put quotes around the path as an argument to your script, and also in the `glob` ([perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)). Then you can use `$ARGV[0]` or `shift(@ARGV)` to get the parameter.

Comment: @MattJacob Thanks for this. You have pointed me to the right direction and the script works. Could you take a look at it and check it and perhaps improve it, please? I edited my first post.

Comment: @menteith I rolled back the edit, because the question doesn't make sense when everything is fixed and working correctly. If you have a different question, you should ask a new question.

Comment: @MattJacob I have asked a [new question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114662/perl-dealing-with-a-command-line-argument-path-with-spaces) on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the pertinent guts for a slightly different approach that cuts down on your code duplication.

We create a dispatch/lookup table to externalize the dissimilar bits of code, keyed off the file extensions you're interested in. In the outer loop, we iterate over those extensions in the order you want (which, luckily, happens to be lexical order in this example). In the inner loop, we filter out files for the current extension and then apply the page creation logic. Finally, we only save the file if the document actually contains some pages.

```
my $pdf = PDF::API2->new;

my %dispatch = (
    jpg => sub { $pdf->image_jpeg(@_) },
    png => sub { $pdf->image_png(@_) },
    tif => sub { $pdf->image_tiff(@_) },
);

my @files = glob("$folder/*");

for my $ext (sort(keys(%dispatch))) {
    my $count;

    for my $file (@files) {
        next unless $file =~ /\.$ext$/;

        my $image = $dispatch{$ext}->($file);
        my $page = $pdf->page;
        $page->mediabox(0, 0, $image->width, $image->height);
        $page->trimbox(0, 0, $image->width, $image->height);
        my $gfx = $page->gfx;
        $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);

        $count++;
    }

    last if $count;
}

if ($pdf->pages) {
    $pdf->saveas($pdf_file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a "new" PDF every time you want to save.
Just add

```
$pdf = PDF::API2->new;
```

Before the second and third foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will get back to you tomorrow since I don't have access to perl right now.

Answer (score -1):

This code more or less implements what I suggested in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339395/perl-three-parts-of-code-works-independently-of-each-other-when-mixed-the-scr?noredirect=1#comment56421824_34339395):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use PDF::API2;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub convert_jpgs
{
    my($pdf, $folder) = @_;
    my $count = 0;
    foreach my $file ( glob "$folder/*.jpg" )
    {
        my $jpg = $file;
        my $image = $pdf->image_jpeg($jpg);
        my $page = $pdf->page();
        $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
        $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
        my $gfx = $page->gfx;
        $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
        $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}

sub convert_pngs
{
    my($pdf, $folder) = @_;
    my $count = 0;
    foreach my $file ( glob "$folder/*.png" )
    {
        my $png = $file;
        my $image = $pdf->image_png($png);
        my $page = $pdf->page();
        $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
        $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
        my $gfx = $page->gfx;
        $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
        $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}

sub convert_tifs
{
    my($pdf, $folder) = @_;
    my $count = 0;
    foreach my $file ( glob "$folder/*.tif" )
    {
        my $tif = $file;
        my $image = $pdf->image_tiff($tif);
        my $page = $pdf->page();
        $page->mediabox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
        $page->trimbox(0,0,$image->width, $image->height);
        my $gfx = $page->gfx;
        $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
        $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}

for my $folder (@ARGV)
{
    # deal with dos paths
    $folder =~ s|\\|/|g;
    $folder =~ s|/$||;

    if (! -d $folder)
    {
        warn "$folder: not a folder! - skipping\n";
        next;
    }

    my $pdf_file = $folder . '.pdf';
    if (-f $pdf_file)
    {
        warn "There's already a pdf $pdf_file! - skipping\n";
        next;
    }

    my $pdf = PDF::API2->new;
    if (convert_jpgs($pdf, $folder) != 0 ||
        convert_pngs($pdf, $folder) != 0 ||
        convert_tifs($pdf, $folder) != 0)
    {
        $pdf->saveas($pdf_file);
    }
    else
    {
        warn "No image files in $folder\n";
    }
}
```

It compiles; it has not been tested.  It changes the interface; it assumes that you might want to process several folders with a single invocation and assumes you type the folder names accurately on the command line, inside double quotes if the names contain spaces, etc.  Thus, if the script is `c3po.pl` (for 'correct three Perl operations' — nothing to do with a new hope, of course, or an awakening force), then you could run, perhaps:

```
perl c3po.pl $HOME/Images/*
```

and it will process the documents in each of the subdirectories under `$HOME/Images`.

Note how each subroutine takes the working code, reads two arguments into local (`my`) variables — the parentheses are important — and creates a new `$counter` which it initializes, increments and returns.  Otherwise, the code in the functions is substantially unchanged from the code you provided.

Note how the driver code (the `for` loop over the argument list) uses `warn` rather than `die` (it isn't necessarily a good idea to stop processing just because there's a minor problem — though it is often a good strategy to exit early), and how the warning messages contain the name of the object that causes trouble (the directory name or the file name).  This makes it much easier to debug — you know what the program was looking for and failed to find.

If you wanted to get fancy, you'd pass a reference to the relevant function from the `PDF::API2` package, and the relevant suffix, so that you could have a single function handling all three image types.  That's slightly more complex than what's shown but avoids more repetition — laziness is good and repetition is bad.  However, if you're struggling with functions in the first place, that's out of scope for a sensible, helpful answer.